# OAuth2.0 and RESTful API

Tags: oauth2

So I'm creating some RESTful API endpoints which use Bearer tokens for authorization. I want to use OAuth2.0 to get the access tokens for these. But I can't get my head around how to get the OAuth2.0  workflow going with the REST framework.

What I've commonly seen till now is that you have webpages which when want to use OAuth2.0 for authorization redirect to the corresponding pages and get the work done. With the REST APIs, how do I do this work of redirecting users? Should I even be doing this? I mean, should I assume that some frontend page will get this authorization workflow done and then the client will have the Bearer token, which it can then use for future API calls?

Basically, my question here is that suppose someone tries to access my APIs through, say python, and wants to authorize my application, what should happen for the OAuth workflow? Should I provide some controller for the authorization - but then how will the python script get around to authorising in the redirected OAuth server page?

Comment: A client will use a OAuth2.0 flow to get an access token. Now, whenever the client makes an API call, it sends the access token in the HTTP Authorization header. The API endpoint verifies the access token. For JWTs, access tokens can be verified without a DB.